# XOR operator with std::ostream operator

Tags: c++, operators, xor, ostream

I wrote a class which represent Qubit. So object has only one value, state, with 0 or 1 (bool). To make needed calculations I overloaded operators like +,*,^. 
It seems that everything is ok with + and *, also with ^, but only if I won't use it with std::ostream operator.

```
Qubit x5, x6;
cout << x5^x6; !ERROR!
```

but with

```
Qubit x5, x6;
Qubit z = x5^x6;
cout << z;
```

it's working. My std:operator

```
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & os, const Qubit & qubit)
{
    os << qubit.GetState();
    return os;
}
```

and my XOR operator

```
Qubit & Qubit::operator ^(const Qubit & qubit)
{
    Qubit *q = new Qubit;
    ((this->state == 1 && qubit.state == 0) ||
        (this->state == 0 && qubit.state == 1)) ? q->SetState(1) : q->SetState(0);
    return *q;
}
```

Comment: Go back to your C++ book, and review the chapter on operator precedence.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: You have a memory leak in your `operator^` function. Also read more about [operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) especially the canonical [binary arithmetic operators section](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Binary_arithmetic_operators). Notice the example which tells you to return *by value* and not by reference.

Comment: With a suitable constructor, `operator^` could be just `return Qubit(state ^ qubit.state);`. (Don't return a reference.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cout << x5 ^ x6` is evaluated as `(cout << x5) ^ x6` due to *operator precedence*.

Since you have not provided an overloaded XOR operator for an `ostream&` and a `Qubit` (or `const Qubit&` etc.), compilation fails.

The solution is to write `cout << (x5 ^ x6);`

(Note that the `+` and `*` operators have higher precedence than `<<` which is why they work as you describe).

Finally, you have a serious memory leak in the XOR operator (who is going to `delete` the allocated memory?). Fix that by changing the function to return a value copy:

`Qubit Qubit::operator^(const Qubit& qubit) const`

and use `Qubit q;` in the function body. *Named Return Value Optimisation* will obviate a value copy. For more details, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic